# How to connect with ODBC and display 'big table' without downloading all data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, odbc

I try to perform connection through ODBC in my program to display table which have 100 000 rows and 20 columns ( 700 MB ) . This program is simply database viewer and it should be as fast as possible, and it doesn't have to display more than 30-50 records at once.

I thought that ODBC connection will automatically call database only for necessary to display records just like virtualization on DataGrid items work for memory, but its not. 
When I use query like

" select * from BigTable "

my program starts downloading whole table and load it into memory.
Is there any way to load only that records that can be visible for me, and not download all the table to memory? But when I scroll down or up in any row in DataGrid load display next rows without any pause.

This is my code for open, close ODBC Connection and bind datatable to DataGrid.

```
   using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("DSN=" + sourceDriver.SelectedValue.ToString() + ";UID=myLogin;PWD=myPSWD" ))
        using (OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command, con))
        {
            try 
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                dadapter.Fill(table);
                dataTable.ItemsSource = null;
                dataTable.Items.Clear();
                dataTable.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
                dataTable.Items.Refresh();
                table = null;

            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

        }
   }
```

Thank You for any help.

Regards

P.S. This code is not very beautiful ( not implement better Exceptions handling ) but its my base for future work.

Comment: Instead of pulling all the columns decide which columns do you need, then go for paging. Define page size, from/to etc.

Comment: Thank You for such quick answers.

Comment: Fill is just that.  It is not going to the next line until it is done.  Fill is not even aware of the datatable.